# update requests.session() header after each request

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies

I'm writing a python client for a RESTful API using [requests.Session](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects). The API generates and returns a new CSRFToken after each request. The Devs of the API told me I need to update the session headers like so:

```
csrf = session.cookies.get('CSRFToken')
session.headers.update({'x-csrf-token': csrf})
```

How can I bind this functionality at a Session object so that this functionality is automatically called after every request (maybe a nice inheritance sollution might be possible) so that it doesn't have to be called by the user after every request?

Comment: You could write your own class that sub-classes the Session object

Comment: @DarkKnight yeah I thought so but do you have a hint where I have to overwrite the Session class? https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/sessions.py here probably in the request function but I don't know where and how exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of what you could do:

```
import requests

class MySession(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.headers = dict()
    def get(self, url):
        if (c := self.cookies.get('CSRFToken')):
            self.headers['x-csrf-token'] = c
        return super().get(url, headers=self.headers)


with MySession() as session:
    (r := session.get('https://www.google.com')).raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast sollution! I updated it so it works for all requests, not only GET. I think __init__ does not have to be overwritten since self.headers = default_headers() exists.

Comment: @LukasWeber Note that I made it clear that this is a **minimal** solution. You will need to do a lot more work to make this production ready. Also, well done for discovering requests.utils

Comment: do you have the rights to approve the edits?